# Gitlab Integrations: "Microsoft Teams notifications" for two different channels

Tags: gitlab

Is there a to configure the "Microsoft Teams notifications" twice, that it will send different notifications to different channels.

In our use case, we want to

1. push notifications for new releases into one channels
2. push notifications of failing builds into another channel

However with the UI, I can only configure "Microsoft Teams notifications" once and select the types of notifications I want to push. I cannot select the "Microsoft Teams notifications" for the other channel. Is there a way to do this?

Screenshot of the Integrations page:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not currently possible in GitLab configuration alone.

To workaround this, you could to configure a generic webhook to point to a custom intermediate service to handle the GitLab event -> Teams channel routing.

Or, perhaps alternatively you could set this up in the pipeline itself using jobs, if your workflow would allow for it. For example, a scheduled pipeline may check for new releases and notify the appropriate channel or a job with `when: on_failure` can notify of build failures. (or use the available integration for one functionality and pipeline for the other).